# How to make bash function return error if syntax error

Tags: bash, error-handling

I made a few changes to a bash script recently, and made a syntax error in a function.  I know what the error is (spaces around the assignment: `local max_loops = 4` instead of `local max_loops=4`).

However, I didn't spot this at first - it's a long script with a lot of output and it just output errors but continued running - the function returned true, so despite testing for success of the function I got no errors.

A simplified version is here (updated based on comments and answers below):

```
!/bin/bash
set -e

do_magic(){
    set -e
    local i=1
    local max_loops
    max_loops = 4   # This is the error i want the script/function to break on
    while [ $i -le $max_loops ]; do
        echo "Loop: $i"
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
}

if do_magic; then
    echo "Ran OK"
else
    echo "Error running...."
fi
```

(My actual function does stuff in the loop and returns an error code if the stuff fails).  This just outputs:

```
$ ./foo.sh
./foo.sh: line 1: !/bin/bash: No such file or directory
./foo.sh: line 8: max_loops: command not found
./foo.sh: line 9: [: 1: unary operator expected
Ran OK
```

My Question: **Is there any generic way to say that functions with unhandled errors return a non-zero value?** I tried `set -e` (I know I shouldn't need it twice, but tried both for safeties sake) and it doesn't seem to help.

I'd be happy either with the whole script breaking and stopping, or with the function breaking and returning a non-zero error.  But i don't want to see "Ran OK" here...

I've fixed the actual error here, but I'd like to make the script more robust.

Comment: Aside: `$[ ]` is a non-POSIX-compliant extension for backward compatibility with ancient 1970s-era shells. Don't ever use it in new code -- `i=$(( i + 1 ))` is the POSIX-standardized syntax.

Comment: ...and `[` isn't bash syntax, so it's not actually a shell syntax error. A failure with it is just the same as if some other random program you were calling were given incorrect command-line arguments, insofar as the shell is concerned. (Yes, it's implemented as a builtin, but they behave identically to external commands insofar as parsing, exit status, error handling, etc etc are concerned).

Comment: (I'd also strongly suggest `do_magic() {` with no `function` -- see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete; `function funcname() {` is an amalgam between POSIX sh and ksh function declaration syntax, while being compatible with neither).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It also took me a while to realize that, but the question is more: "Why does the script not fail on `local max_loops = 4`, even if `set -e` is in place?"

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...ahh -- yeah, this could have been **much** more clearly asked -- there's no reason for the function to have more than than one `local` line as its [mcve].

Comment: I couldn't more agree

Comment: Sorry, the `local STATUS=` is unnecessary. I'll remove it.The `local i=1` is needed to make the example work when fixing the error, which I thought would be helpful. I did say in line 2 what the error in my example was.  However, my question, as explicitly stated, is not _"how do I break on this specific error?"_ but _"Is there any *generic* way to say that *functions with unhandled errors* return a non-zero value?"_ (emphasis added). I had expected `if some_function` to be false if the function throws unhandled errors (as it would if the function was a separate command instead) - not in bash?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yes, the actual script is one i inherited and I just cleaned out the irrelevant stuff for the example.  Quite right about `i=$(( i+1 ))` and `function`.  have updated the example 8and will update the real script.  Thanks

Comment: I take back the part about a separate script.  Seems even if I refactor the function to a script, it behaves the same unless I `set -e` in that script.  But `set -e` doesn't help the function version

Answer (score 3):

Basically syntax errors can't be handled by code because the syntax has to be parsed before the code can run. I think this is what you assume.

---

However, in this case it is not a syntax error in bash, it is a syntax error raised by the `[` (or `test`) command builtin.

Note that `[` is an external* command, it is more or less an alias to the `test` command. You can replace:

```
[ 1 -lt 2 ]
```

by:

```
test 1 -lt 2
```

for example.

This kind of error can only be detected at runtime of the bash script, and the bash script won't fail by default It is just like any other command that fails. Well, with one exception: If you use `set -e`, the `[` command won't fail the script.

<sub>* nowadays realized as a bash builtin. but it is not bash *syntax*</sub>

---

How to solve it?

`bash` offers the `[[` (extended comparison) for this (plus other advantages):

```
foo() {
    # Oops! missing the dash in front of 'lt'      
    if [[ 1 lt 2 ]] ; then
        echo "foo"
    fi  
}

echo "Don't print this"    
foo
echo "And this"
```

Since the `[[` is `bash` syntax, not an external command, bash can handle this error at parsing stage, before the code runs. The result is that script doesn't run at all.

Comment: it would, except that the script continues running after the syntax error!  if it just bailed out, then I'd be fine with that...  it's the fail-and-continue behaviour I don't like

Comment: Ah sorry, I got it wrong. This is not a bash syntax error, it is a `test` syntax error. Let me rephrase my answer...

Comment: Well, it's both `local` and test that complain...  But yes, maybe not a strict bash syntax error

Comment: No, it is not a bash error at all. For bash the `[` just looks like this `[ SOME_STRING ]`. `SOME_STRING` will be parsed by `[` Do you see my point?

Comment: As I said, it's *not* just the test.  The actual error is on the variable assignment above.  I get two errors from the `local max_loops` line (line 6) and one from the test line (line 7) as in the output I show.  If I change to `[[` then the only difference is I don't get an error from the test line.  i still get errors from the variable definition (line 6) but nothing from test - but the end result is the same: it treats the function call as successful even though errors were created and the loop didn't run

Comment: I see. You can use `set -e`. In that case the script would fail at that point.

Comment: yeah, it should.  But it doesn't!  I added `set -e` before the function definition and I still get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set -e`.

Example (t.sh):

```
set -e
x = r
echo hello
```

Execution:

```
$ bash t.sh
t.sh: line 3: x: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

EDIT:
And you need to change the `if do_magic` as follows:

```
do_magic
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that.  Most advice is to avoid -e if you can, but I could try it.  But I tried it and it doesn't work for functions like this.  I added `set -e` directly after the `#!/bin/bash` in my example script.  i still get the errors output then "Ran OK"...

Comment: The only reason I can imagine why your program does not stop is because you spawn subprocesses (with &), and these die, but the main program does not.

Comment: Look at my example program.  no sub-processes or &

Comment: The "if do_magic" part breaks the error detection. I updated my answer.

Comment: If `set -e` has been run, then the `[ $? -eq 0 ]` is pointless: If it *isn't* 0, then the `if` statement will never be reached.

Comment: @Charles: correct for the given example. But in a more general case, the `[ $? -eq 0 ]` is useful for errors other than those caught by `set -e`. Eg: if do_magic returns explicitely an error code.

Comment: @user803422, if `do_magic` "returns explicitly an error code", `set -e` *will* abort. See `bash -c 'f() { return 1; }; set -e; f; echo "reached with value $?"'` -- you never get to `reached`.

Comment: (See also the exercises -- below the allegory -- in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) re: the reasoning behind the common advice to avoid `set -e` where possible, as referenced by the OP above; also see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ for tables detailing differences between how various "POSIX-compliant" shells behave when `set -e` is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `syntax error`, but one of the most common Bash `pitfalls`

The `local` keyword is a Bash builtin. Be careful with `local`, because for historical reasons this statement returns a `success status` that you might **not expect** (Bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-local)). Here is an example:

```
local x=$(false) # $? == 0
```

vs.

```
local x
x=$(false)       # $? == 1
```

But in your case, the expression

```
local max_loops = 4
```

is equivalent to

```
local max_loops
local = # error, $? == 1 - an invalid name is supplied
local 4 # error, $? == 1
```

So, you have a command with the nonzero return status. Making script exit automatically with the `-errexit` shell flag doesn't help because of the execution context of `do_magic`, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html).

The following will work fine with `set -e`

```
do_magic
echo "Ran OK"
```

Just remember that if you rely on `set -e`, never change the context. Even executing your script as

```
if ./do_magic.sh; then
    :
fi
```

enough for `set -e` magic to disappear.

Comment: I have changed to having `local max_loops` on it's own line and  `max_loops = 4` on the line below that.  I also `set -e` at the top of the script (before the function definition - and also even tried inside it).  Nothing helps.  I still get errors in the console and then `Ran OK`

Comment: @Adam, the following does not print "Success": set -e; local max_loops = 4; echo Success; but script reports error and exits

Comment: Yeah, but if the error is inside the function it seems to swallow it and still return true

Comment: Why not to verify that? set -e; foo() { local max_loops = 4; }; foo; echo Success;